# Issue in creating drop down list using VBA. Code mentioned below creates drop down list but needs repair every time the file is reopened

Tags: excel, vba, validation, dropdown

The code mentioned below is generating dropdown list 0-100 for each cell up to 1500 rows. Although once this excel file is reopened it crashes and shifts to auto-recovery stating "Removed Feature: Data validation from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part". This leads to first saving the recovered file and then proceeding with the work. Please help me to find and resolve the issue.

```
Private Sub sSlot_Number()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim Astr As String
i = 0
j = 0

For j = 0 To 100
   Astr = Astr & "," & j          'To contain 0 to 100 numbers in Astr for creating dropdown list
Next j

Do While i < 1499
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2 + i, 2).Validation
 .Delete
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
 Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Astr        'Drop down list with value 0 to 100 for cells upto Row 1500
 .IgnoreBlank = True
 .InCellDropdown = True
 .InputTitle = ""
 .ErrorTitle = ""
 .InputMessage = ""
 .ErrorMessage = ""
 .ShowInput = True
 .ShowError = True
End With
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The length limit for `Formula1` is 256 characters: you have 294 characters in `Astr`.  You could set up equivalent validation without using a list, or you could point the validation to a list range on a (hidden) worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.