# Error when I open a workbook (we found a problem with some content in"workbook name", do you want us to try to recover as much as we can)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, validation

I'm coding a workbook that validates cells in many sheets based on the data stored in a MS Access database, and based on the selection from those cells, it fetches related data, very simple and straight forward code and everything works fine as long as the workbook is open and running.

When I close the workbook and open it again, I get the error in the title, I choose yes to recover and Excel moves the code from some sheets (which is actually just calling subroutines from the modules when a change happens or when the sheet is active) to a new sheet and cancel all the formatting for that sheet.

I've been trying to figure out the problem for a week now, what am I missing?

I tried isolating some of the code and it worked, then suddenly the error appeared again in different sheets with no subroutines in common with the previously troubled sheets.

sample of the code im using:

```
Sub ValidateIdCode()

Call establish_conn
Call open_conn
Dim Icode As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim rngcode As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indoor")
lr = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 8 To lr
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
        rs.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Model] FROM tblData WHERE [Brand] = '" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("General").Cells(7, 4).Value & "' AND [Description2] = '" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value & "' AND [Sub] = '" & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value & "';", conn
        Icode = ""
        Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields("Model").Value <> "" Then
        Icode = Icode & rs.Fields("Model").Value & ","
        rs.MoveNext
        End If
        Loop
        If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set rngcode = ws.Range("C" & i)
        If Len(Icode) > 0 Then
        Icode = Left(Icode, Len(Icode) - 1)
                
    
                With rngcode.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Icode

                End With
            Else
                
                With rngcode.Validation
                    .Delete
                End With
            
        End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code add any data validation to the sheets?  What exactly is it doing?  Kind of difficult to suggest any solutions without more detail.

Comment: You can edit your question and add code there.

Comment: the code is supposed to validate cells based on selection on other cells, i added sample of the code in the origional post

Comment: `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Icode` There's a limit to the length of string you can safely use in this type of validation.  If you assign a string >256 characters it can cause problems when re-opening the file

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142004/issue-in-creating-drop-down-list-using-vba-code-mentioned-below-creates-drop-do/62142444#62142444

Comment: ....if you have a long list you'd need to (eg) place it on a hidden sheet and link the validation to the list.

Comment: that was it, problem solved thank you :)